# Keep socket connection (TCP) when switching activity

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, tcp, tcpclient

In the first activity I enter IP and port which connects the client to the server and a new activity opens. Is there an “easy” way to keep the connection alive using Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

By using [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) you can achieve this, move all your network connection code into service, for all activities that want to use socket connection, bind your network service in `onCreate()` then after finish unbind it in `onDestory()`